# Terminology of types

Tags: java, types, naming-conventions

I'm getting a little lost as far as how java types are separated. There's the obvious primitive types that I use (beginner), but what are the rest of them grouped as?  I've found conflicting results, oracle docs calls them all "reference types", but I've seen textbooks call them "class types".  But when doing general searches for data types, no one calls them either and just refers to their individual types and that each is technically a class of it's own, but no one uses the words "class types".  Is "class types" even a thing?

Comment: I would use either "reference type" or "object type". I would understand what "class type" means, but it's not a term I would use.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of classes are wrappers of the primitive data types, and can be use as any other class, with no special name for them. The only particular thing is you don't need to import them as they are in the java.lang package.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. I don't think the OP is talking specifically about the object wrappers for primitive types, but rather object/reference types in general.

Answer (score 0):

"Class types, object types and reference types all mean the exact same thing - an object of a class." [[Source](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-a-primitive-type-and-a-class-type/)]